# FFmpeg does not encode chapter titles

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I am trying to add chapters to a .mp4 file.
When I tried extracting the metadata using the following command:

`ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -f ffmetadata FFMETADATAFILE.txt`

I got an output file as follows:

```
;FFMETADATA1
major_brand=mp42
minor_version=0
compatible_brands=isommp42
encoder=Lavf60.15.100
```

So now I try to add some chapters as such

```
[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0
END=424510
title=mytitle1

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=424511
END=941600
title=mytitle2

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=941601
END=1227260
title=mytitle3
```

I use the `ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -i FFMETADATAFILE.txt -map_metadata 1 -codec copy OUTPUT.mp4` command to encode the metadata to my video file, and for some reason I only ever get 'Chapter 0', 'Chapter 1', and 'Chapter 2'.

I tried using the `-map_chapters 1` argument as well but results have been unchanged.

I am using the `Latest Auto-Build (2023-10-14 13:02)` Windows build by BtbN. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the latest version by BtbN and gyan.dev **does** have an issue, because the chapters encoded just fine when I used the version 5.1.2 build by gyan.dev.

I previously tried using the release version 6.0 but it had the same problem, so the solution is to simply use release version 5.1.2.

Comment: Possibly related: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/10482